# Execute a command bash in javascript whithout ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, shell, google-chrome, firefox, command

I search to execute a bash command in js without ActiveXObject because it's doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. Have you got a solutions?
Thank's

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but as far as i know bash command and ActiveX do not mix, and running "bash" commands from an explorer is a huge security breach. Could you provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible on a client side.
On the other hand if you want to execute command on the server side (Node.js) you could use the [child_proccess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module from Node.js API.

Below you can find an example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
        child;

    child = exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
```